# Take text by class name Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to get 2 as number for future using (2)

```
<div class="pageCont">
<span class="link">
<span class="page">
<span class="page active">2</span>
</div>
```

I have tried `alert(jQuery(".page active").text());` do not work because I use 2 parameters. I do not know how to tell jquery to show

pageCont->active

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `$('.page.active').text();`

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because it says, find me something with the class `page` that contains an element called `active.` Like

```
<div class="page">
    <active></active>
</div>
```

Others have already given you the correct answer, but you might as well as know what's wrong with your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourInt = $('.page.active').text();
```